# ScrollBy по клику

Tags: прокрутка, javascript

```
Доброго здоровьица, прошу помощи.
Нужен js, благодаря которому при клике по <span id='down'>Ниже</span>.
Блок с идентификатором "secondline" будет прокручиваться вниз на 150 пикселей, причем прокрутка нужна при каждом нажатии на "<span id='down'>Ниже</span>", а не только при первом.
Благодарю за внимание и помощь.
```

Comment: @Владимир01, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Дело в том что в js вообще не силен.
Пытался писать onclick='secondline.scrollBy(0,150)', но это не работает. Перечитал несколько "учебников" но ответа не нашел как именно это реализовать.

Мудрил еще с 

<a href='#' onclick="scrollWin()">Вниз</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollWin()
{
var block = document.getElementById('secondline');
block.scrollBy(0,150);
}
</script>

Но тоже ничего не вышло.

Comment: Все. Разобрался сам.
Решил вопрос следующим образом:
<a href='#' onclick="document.getElementById('secondline').scrollTop+=150">Ниже</a>